The .bg-* utility class of tailwindcss doesn't seem to work
I looked at the issues at GitHub and since it used to work in my project it's probably a configuration problem instead of a bug so I don't want to open a new issue.
I have a React project that uses tailwindcss. All of the utility classes work as intended, except the .bg-* ones. The custom theme ones work but for some reason the built-in colors do not. The .text-* ones work so it must not be a `tailwind.config.js issue. Here is my configuration:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                paper: {
                    300: "#1a1a1c",
                    400: "#25272b",
                    500: "#151417"
                }
            },
            keyframes: {
                slideLeftAndFade: {
                    from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(2px)" },
                    to: { opacity: 1, transform: "translateX(0)" }
                }
            },
            animation: {
                slideLeftAndFade:
                    "slideLeftAndFade 400ms cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.3, 1)"
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: []
};

Here's the snippet of the React component that does not work:
function DrawerItem({
    label,
    icon,
    background
}: DrawerItemProps) {
    const clsRoot = clsx(
        `flex items-center justify-center h-14 w-14 rounded bg-${background}-400/20`
    );
    // background prop is a string of built-in color such as 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', etc...

    return (
        ...
        <button className={clsRoot}>
            <Icon icon={icon} width={32} />
        </button>
        ...
    );
}

The problem is that when I inspect the button from the DevTools, all of the other utilities are working properly except for the background color. The background color of my custom color paper work. Here is a screenshot so you can see it yourself:
Screenshot of the DevTools
I kind of tried everything I could think of but I am running out of ideas. It isn't the theme, it isn't the index.css @include's, it isn't the clsx helper either...
I was expecting to see the .bg-green-400/20 class in the DevTools.

check your css file, it probably does not contain such class because it's dynamic generated by variable, to check it write directly bg-green-400/20 instead of variable

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Have the entire class in the variable you pass to background like
function DrawerItem({
  label,
  icon,
  background
}: DrawerItemProps) {
  const clsRoot = clsx(
    `flex items-center justify-center h-14 w-14 rounded ${background}
  );

<DrawerItem background="bg-red-400/20">


Have a dictionary for background to Tailwind class names:
function DrawerItem({
  label,
  icon,
  background
}: DrawerItemProps) {
  const backgrounds = {
    red: 'bg-red-400/20',
    green: 'bg-green-400/20',
    blue: 'bg-blue-400/20',
  };
  const clsRoot = clsx(
    `flex items-center justify-center h-14 w-14 rounded ${backgrounds[background]}
  );


safelist the classes, if you have a limited number of known colors:
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^bg-(red|green|blue)-400\/20$/ },
    // …
  ],
  // …
];



